# Adding path objects to arraylist

Tags: android, arraylist, path, android-canvas, draw

I have created a path objects as shown below which draws a different shapes.Different buttons response to drawing different shapes on the canvas. I am trying to save the path every time when the button is invoked into a arraylist and redraw all the path on a canvas every time the arraylist is being increased.

```
        public class DrawImage extends SurfaceView {
            ArrayList<Path> paths = new ArrayList<Path>();
        Path path = new Path();

                 @Override
                protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    super.onDraw(canvas);


            if (MainActivity.isRectangle) {


                        path.moveTo(1, 1);
                        path.lineTo(90, 1);
                        path.lineTo(90, 60);
                        path.lineTo(1, 60);

                        path.close();


                        paintColor.setColor(Color.RED);
                        paintColor.setStrokeWidth(2);
                        paintColor.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

                        paths.add(path);

             for (Path p : paths) {
                    canvas.drawPath(p, paintColor);
                }

                    }
if (MainActivity.isTriangle) {

                  path.moveTo(0, 40);
                  path.lineTo(50, 0);
                  path.lineTo(50, 50);
                  path.lineTo(50, 50);
                  path.lineTo(0, 40);

                        path.close();


                        paintColor.setColor(Color.RED);
                        paintColor.setStrokeWidth(2);
                        paintColor.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

                        paths.add(path);

             for (Path p : paths) {
                    canvas.drawPath(p, paintColor);
                }

                    }



            }
```

And this is my mainActivity

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        dI = new DrawImage(this);

        rectbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pointerbutton);


        RelativeLayout mainLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        // add here other layout params rules to make your
        // custom view stay below the buttons

        lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.rectbutton);

        dI.setLayoutParams(lp);

        mainLayout.addView(dI);

rectbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                isTriangle = false;
                isRectangle = true;
                isCircle= false;
                isParallelogram = false;
                isTapezium = false;


                dv.invalidate();


            }// onclick

        });

trianglebutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {

                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    isTriangle = true;
                    isRectangle = false;
                    isCircle= false;
                    isParallelogram = false;
                    isTapezium = false;


                    dv.invalidate();


                }// onclick

            });
```

Problem: the two path objects overlaps and when the rect button or triangle button is invoke for the second time,  the new path objects does not appear.

Please advice Thank you.

**Amendments to the DrawImage class**

```
 public class DrawImage extends SurfaceView  {


    Paint paintColor = new Paint();

    Path path = new Path();

    Canvas canvas;

    float x = 0, y = 0;


    public static ArrayList<Path> paths = new ArrayList<Path>();


    public DrawImage(Context context) {

        super(context);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        Paint background = new Paint();
        background.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        canvas.drawARGB(255, 255, 255, 255);

        paintColor.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        paintColor.setStrokeWidth(2);
        paintColor.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

        for (Path p : paths) {
            canvas.drawPath(p, paintColor);
        }

    }


    public void addRectangle() {

        Path path = new Path();

          path.moveTo(x+1, y+1);
              path.lineTo(x+90, y+1);
              path.lineTo(x+90, y+60);
              path.lineTo(x+1, y+60);

        path.close();
        paths.add(path);
    }


}
```

**Amendments to the mainActivity**

```
layout.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

            x = event.getX();

            y = event.getY();

            et1.setText(String.valueOf(x));
            et2.setText(String.valueOf(x));

            break;

        }
        dv.invalidate();
        return true;

    }
});
```

}

Comment: Well, there's no code that would put anything into the array list, so of course it is empty.

Comment: @Ridcully I have made amendments to the question.

Comment: I have the impression that you do not understand the code you're using. The `ArrayList<Path> paths` you have in your class never gets anything added to it, so when you iterate over it later on, nothing gets rendered.

Comment: @Ridcully I am sorry, I am in the mid of self learning. In my code, "paths.add(path);" adds the path to the arraylist I have declared. So the method i used is wrong? I did a debug and my array is empty. If possible would you gave me an example of adding path to the arraylist? or correct me? Thank you

Comment: Sorry, I missed that line. Still, it's a very strange way to do this. In my answer I'll try to suggest a better way.

Answer (score 1):

Its a simple problem that is occuring over here in your code.

See when you do `Paths.add(path)` - It stores the address of the path as its an object.

Rather than this do `Paths.add(new Path(path))` - Now this will create a new object which will be stored in the `arraylist`.

Now why are you getting a blank path ?

The reason is simple when you do `path.reset()`, the path gets empty and the `arraylist` is pointing to that same address which has now be resetted.

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this:

Add a method `addRectangle()` to your `DrawImage` class (and a similar one for triangles...)

```
public void addRectangle() {
     Path path = new Path();
     path.moveTo(1, 1);
     path.lineTo(90, 1);
     path.lineTo(90, 60);
     path.lineTo(1, 60);
     path.close();
     paths.add(path);
}
```

Reduce your `draw` method to this (actually, for performance, you also should initialize the `Paint` object only once and not every time `onDraw` is called.

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
     paintColor.setColor(Color.RED);
     paintColor.setStrokeWidth(2);
     paintColor.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
     for (Path p : paths) {
         canvas.drawPath(p, paintColor);
     }
}
```

In your `MainActivity` get rid of all the static `isRectangle`... variables, instead in the `onClick` method of e.g. your rectangle button do this (I assume here, that `dv` is your `DrawImage` instance:

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {
        dv.addRectangle();
        dv.invalidate();
}
```

Note, that all rectangles are drawn at the same position, so there will be no difference on how many you add. But you can easily extend the `addRectangle()` method to pass a starting position, rectangle size etc.

Also note, I think the main mistake in your code is, that you have defined `path` as a global variable in your `DrawImage`, because of that you're always adding the same object to the list and therefore the list will always only contain that single object.

Comment: Sorry i did not have my computer with me, and i had tried out your method of adding rectangle onto the canvas and it works. However i would like the rectangle only to be drawn after a button click and a touch on the canvas. And now, its rectangle path is fix, i would like it to be drawn based on the user's touch coordinate.I have wrote a ontouch method to fetch the x and y of the user's touch and based on the value of x and y, move the path to the position (path.moveTo(x,y) and draw the rectangle. Could you advice me on the codes i wrote? Is it the correct?

Comment: I am now able to draw the rectangle only after a button click and touch on canvas. However, I am having problems of fetching x and y of the user's touch.

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code? Getting the x and y from the event seems to be okay. However it should be enough to set x, y only for one of ACTION_DOWN or ACTION_UP. No need to do it for all three actions.

Comment: I am able to fetch the x and y value based on the onTouch method in in the mainActivity.I could not pass the x and y value to the DrawImage class and the value of x and y reflected to be 0 when i do a debug. i got my codes updated once again. Please advice thank you.

Comment: I'm sorry but this gets way out of the scope of your original question. Perhaps you should start out with some easier programs or seek some basic Java tutorials.

Comment: I'm sorry! But thank you for your help! I manage to get it working.